# Use __str__ children classes methods when calling parent class

Tags: python, django, django-models, inheritance

I've some classes like these :

```
class Event(models.Model):
    beginning = models.fields.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True, default=date.today)
    end = models.fields.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True, default=date.today)

class Festival(models.Model):
    name = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

class FestivalEdition(Event):
    type = "festival_edition"
    father_festival = models.ForeignKey(Festival, default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="edition")    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.festival_name} {self.year}"
```

As you can see, only the children classes have their `__str__` methods. When I use `Event` (by the admin interface or by shell), the name is like this `<Event: Event object (1)>`.

How can I use the `__str__` methods of the children (and children of children) classes when calling the parent class ?

I've read the [official documentation of Django about inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937660/handling-recurring-events-in-a-django-calendar-app).

I tried this :

```
class Event(models.Model):

    objects2 = InheritanceManager()

    # The __str__ of Event call the __str__ of children models
    def __str__(self) -> str:        
        event_name = Event.objects2.filter(pk=self.pk).select_subclasses()[0].__str__()        
        return f"{event_name}"
```

It works well but only with the children but not the children of the children because I get this recursion Error in this case : `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Comment: You don't need to call `__str__` explicitly. `x.__str__()` is called implicitly when you pass `x` to `str`, or use `x` in a f-string like `f'...{x}...'`.

Comment: It's a weird setup. Usually children call parent methods. Not the other way around. Why you are doing it like this? Maybe instead of inheritance you want to use proxy models?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "When I use `Event`". If you have some instance  `x` of a subclass of `Event`, you wouldn't need to know which subclass it is. `str(x)` will use `x.__str__`, and attribute lookup will find `__str__` on the first class in the MRO of `type(x)` that defines it.

Comment: And if you have a "bare" instance of `Event`, not associated with any specific subclass, then which subclass's `__str__` event do you think is appropriate to use and why?

Comment: Inheritance and relational databases often do not work quite well. I would advise not to use it, unless as a final resort. Very often it is not necessary anyway. There are Django modules that make extra JOINs with all child models to automatically subclass, but these result in quite expensive queries on the database.

Comment: When I have a Festival object, I want that `print(festival)` (festival is a Festival instance) gives me something like "Rolling Swing" and `print(festival_edition)` (festival_edition is a FestivalEdition instance) gives me something like "Rolling Swing 2023". I don't have any "bare" instance of Event, so maybe I should have declared Event as abstract but I decided to use multi-heritance table to enable to user it to look for all types of Event (`Event.objects.all()` for example) as I read in another post. Maybe I should use Event as an abstract base class or, on the contrary, proxy models...

Comment: Furthermore, I didn't precise it but Festival and FestivalEdition have other fields and methods that I didn't write, so I don't think that proxy models are convenient in my situation as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Comment: `print(festival)` will always use `type(festival).__str__`; `Event.__str__` is only relevant if you use `super().__str__` in the definitions of `Festival.__str__`, etc.

Comment: I deleted my InheritanceManager() and the __str__ of Event. I get this when I use the shell :
```>>> Event.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Event: Event object (1)>, <Event: Event object (2)>, <Event: Event object (3)>, <Event: Event object (7)>]>
>>> Festival.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Festival: Rolling Swing>, <Festival: Budafest>, <Festival: Salsa West>]>```

So, it seems that `Event.__str__` didn't call `Festival.__str__`.

Comment: I've just discover polymorphic models. It seems to be the right solution. I'll check this.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by using the `PolymorphicModel` for my model `Event` ! All is said at the [home page of the documentation](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html): "When a query is made at the base model, the inherited model classes are returned."

Not only it returns the `__str__` methods of the subclasses (and subsubclasses and so on) as I asked, but it also enables to make `Event.objects.all()` and get all the `Event` objects with their type and their name as defined in the `__str__` methods of the subclasses (and subsubclasses).